# Laravel Eloquent many to many using with() returning empty array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and Eloquent and have a many to many relationship setup as follows

```
images
+----+---------------+------------------+
| id |  image_name   |  image_location  |
+----+---------------+------------------+
|  1 | kittens.jpg   | C:\kittens.jpg   |
|  2 | puppies.jpg   | C:\puppies.jpg   |
|  3 | airplanes.jpg | C:\airplanes.jpg |
|  4 | trains.jpg    | C:\trains.jpg    |
+----+---------------+------------------+

image_set (pivot table)
+------------+----------+
| set_id     | image_id |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        1 |
|          1 |        2 |
|          2 |        3 |
|          2 |        4 |
+------------+----------+

sets
+----+----------------+
| id |  description   |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | cute animals   |
|  2 | transportation |
|  3 | food           |
+----+----------------+
```

I created a belongsToMany relationship in my photos and sets models to link these two together.

```
class Image extends Model {

    public function sets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Set');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Set extends Model {

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Image');
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is perform a query that only gives me the `sets` that have `images` associated with them.  Essentially join the `sets` and `image_set` table to only return sets of `1,2`

I currently have a rather long query that works...

```
$availSets = Set::join('image_set','image_set.set_id','=','sets.id')
        ->groupBy('sets.id')
        ->get();
```

But I've seen plenty of examples that this should also work.

```
$availSets = Set::with('images')->get();
```

However it's returning all 3 sets, including those that have no associated images.

```
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "images" => Collection {#179 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]
```

Am I using this incorrectly?  Is `with()` supposed to work this way?

Comment: Your class is `Images` so in your relation it should be `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Images');`

Comment: That's a typo, I'll make the correction.  The actual class is called 'Image'

Comment: oh okay. please paste your code to avoid typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `has()` method, not the `with()` method:

```
$availSets = Set::has('images')->get();
```

This will return all the sets that have at least one image. The documentation for this can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations).

The `with()` method is used to eager load the given relationship. It does not put any restraints on retrieving the parent records. You can read more on eager loading [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading).